# CardView not displaying within RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Before you ask, yes I know there are many questions that are very similar to this and I have tried most of them to no avail. My problem is that a CardView is not displaying within a RecyclerView. The items whithin it are displaying but not the card itself.

Without further or do, here's my code:

**Adapter:**

```
Integer count = 0;
Boolean isStart = true;
String datag = "";
String typeg = "";
Integer LastItemType=0; //0=None 1=Text 2=Image
ViewHolder a;
@Override
public EntryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    a= createholder(parent, viewType);
    return(a);
}
public ViewHolder createholder(ViewGroup parent, int viewtype) {

        if (typeg.equals("image")) {
            View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) 
                    .inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
            CardView card = (CardView) root.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.Img);
            ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.card_view));
            if (LastItemType == 2) {
                ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.Img));
            }
            if (LastItemType == 1) {
                ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.Txt));
            }
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(image, card);
            LastItemType = 2;
            return vh;
        } else {
            if (typeg.equals("text")) {
                View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) 
                        .inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
                CardView card = (CardView) root.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                TextView image = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.Txt);
                ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.card_view));
                if (LastItemType == 1) {
                    ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.Txt));
                }
                if (LastItemType == 2) {
                    ((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.Img));
                }
                ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(image, card);
                LastItemType = 1;
                return vh;
            }
            return null; //TODO: REMOVE!
        }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EntryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Deal with data

}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgg;
    public TextView txtg;
    public CardView cardg;
    public ViewHolder(ImageView image, CardView card) {
        super(image);
        imgg = image;
        cardg = card;
}
    public ViewHolder(TextView text, CardView card) {
        super(text);
        txtg = text;
        cardg = card;
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return count;
}
public void refresh(String data, String type, ViewGroup parent) {
    isStart = false;
    datag = data;
    typeg = type;
    count++;
    createholder(parent, -100);
}
```

**listitems.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Img"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:id="@+id/Txt"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Please can you attach screen shots :)

Comment: Try **android:layout_width="match_parent"**  and **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** on the cardview

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Sorry! That din't work either.

Comment: please provide a screen shot

Comment: I'd check the Theme. Are you changing CardView theme directly or maybe indirectly in your styles?

Comment: Sorry, @AtifAbbAsi I haven't been able to check this for a while and I'm now so glad that it works! Here you go, have +50!

Comment: Thanks @I'monstackexchange Coding is Fun and Fixing Bug is damn Interesting Thing to me.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your RecyclerView show ImageView or TextView only?
If yes, because your ViewHolder Constructor is wrong. You have to call super(itemView) in your ViewHolder's Constructor, itemView is the view which is displayed as a row in RecyclerView. To fix your issue, I think you should change your code as below:

```
public ViewHolder createholder(ViewGroup parent, int viewtype) {
    if (typeg.equals("image") || typeg.equals("text")) {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) 
                    .inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(root, typeg.equals("text"));
    }
    //FIXME: As my expericence you should NOT return null for ViewHolder. You have to sure the typeg is one of "image" or "text". I think you should change typeg to Boolean variable to not return null ViewHolder.
    return null;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgg;
    public TextView txtg;
    public CardView cardg;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView, boolean isTypeText) {
        super(itemView);
        imgg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Img);
        cardg = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        txtg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Txt);
        imgg.setVisibility(isTypeText ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        txtg.setVisibility(isTypeText ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out my code, i use it for each of my app after modifying it slightly. You can also use adapter if you have more than one RecyclerViews by changing it's type field and layout and views accordingly. It contains a CoordinatorLayout that has CollapsingLayout with ImageView in it. It contains many layouts for Material Design, i hope it helps.

Activity contains RecyclerView and CardView, i removed things like database, Floating action buttons that you may not need and may make it more difficult to understand. If you need the whole class contact me.

```
public class MeasureListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements MeasureListAdapter.OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener {
// Views
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MeasureListAdapter mAdapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;

// List that keeps values displayed on the screen
private List<Measure> listMeasure;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prev_measures);
    setViews();
}



private void setViews() {
    /*
     * Set toolbar and arrow icon to return back
     */
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarPrevMeasure);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Enable home button for API < 14
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    // Enable home button for API >= 14
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    /*
     * RecylerView to display items as a list
     */
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPrevMeasure);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mAdapter = new MeasureListAdapter(this, listMeasure, 0);

    // Attach an instance of OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener that
    // implements itemClicked()
    mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void itemMeasureClicked(View view, int position) {

}
```

}

```
public class MeasureListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MeasureListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Measure> data = Collections.emptyList();
// This is for delegating event from adapter's onClick() method to
// NavigationDrawerFragment
private OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener recyclerClickListener;
private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;
private int type = 0;
private Context mContext;

public MeasureListAdapter(Context context, List<Measure> data, int type) {
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
    this.type = type;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return data.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Measure measure = data.get(position);
    String title = measure.getTitle();
    String note = measure.getNote();
    String date = measure.getFormattedDate();
    double angle = measure.getAnglePhoto();
    // Compass
    double azimuth = measure.getAngleAzimuth();
    double pitch = measure.getAnglePitch();
    double roll = measure.getAngleRoll();
    String bearing = measure.getBearing();

    holder.tvTitle.setText(title);
    holder.tvNote.setText(note);
    holder.tvAngle.setText(
            mContext.getString(R.string.angle) + ": " + decimalFormat.format(angle) + ConstantsApp.DEGREE_ICON);
    // Compass
    holder.tvAzimuth.setText(
            mContext.getString(R.string.azimuth) + ": " + decimalFormat.format(azimuth) + ConstantsApp.DEGREE_ICON);
    holder.tvPitch.setText(
            mContext.getString(R.string.pitch) + ": " + decimalFormat.format(pitch) + ConstantsApp.DEGREE_ICON);
    holder.tvRoll.setText(
            mContext.getString(R.string.roll) + ": " + decimalFormat.format(roll) + ConstantsApp.DEGREE_ICON);
    holder.tvBearing.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.bearing) + " " + bearing);

    holder.tvDate.setText("Date" + ": " + measure.getFormattedDate());
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
    View view = null;

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_angle_photo, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

/**
 * get an instance of OnRecyclerViewClickListener interface
 * 
 * @param OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener
 *            callback that is used by adapter to invoke the method of the
 *            class implements the OnRecyclerViewClickListener interface
 */
public void setClickListener(OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener recyclerClickListener) {
    this.recyclerClickListener = recyclerClickListener;
}

public void delete(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Views
    private TextView tvTitle, tvNote, tvAngle, tvAzimuth, tvPitch, tvRoll, tvBearing, tvDate;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayTitle);
        tvAngle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayAngle);
        // Compass
        tvAzimuth = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayAzimuth);
        tvPitch = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayPitch);
        tvRoll = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayRoll);
        tvBearing = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayBearing);

        tvNote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayNote);
        tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDate);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (recyclerClickListener != null) {
            recyclerClickListener.itemMeasureClicked(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * RecyclerViewClickListener interface helps user to set a clickListener to
 * the RecyclerView. By setting this listener, any item of Recycler View can
 * respond to any interaction.
 * 
 * @author Fatih
 *
 */
public interface OnRecyclerViewMeasureClickListener {
    /**
     * This is a callback method that be overriden by the class that
     * implements this interface
     */
    public void itemMeasureClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

}

Measure class only contains setters and getters for int and String values so i don't put it.

Layout for Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutMainMeasure"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarPrevMeasure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarPrevMeasure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backgroundPrevMeasure"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_material" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPrevMeasure"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPrevMeasure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:paddingTop="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="80dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarPrevMeasure"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white_36dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFA500" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabClearDB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarPrevMeasure"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_36dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#D463C3" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout for adapter rows with CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardRecord"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#eeeeee"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
cardview:cardElevation="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplayTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplayAngle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/angle_"
            android:textColor="#525657"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplayAzimuth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/angle_"
            android:textColor="#525657"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplayBearing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/angle_"
            android:textColor="#525657"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplayPitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:text="@string/angle_"
            android:textColor="#525657"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplayRoll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:text="@string/angle_"
            android:textColor="#525657"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplayDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/date_"
        android:textColor="#9EA9AD"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplayNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#828A8C"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How it looks
[image: Coordinator Layout RecyclerView Carview Combo]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)  Read and And Follow it.
You must be Doing Something Wrong in Gradle.!
so, the issue was Your XML was not showing CardView in it here we go.!

Add following Dependencies.!

```
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'


     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

[image]

Here is Your XML is Working Perfectly Fine.!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/Img"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="150dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:id="@+id/Txt"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now Clean and Rebuild Your Project.!
ok try this its Working Fine.now.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are removing `card_view` like so?

```
((ViewGroup)image.getParent()).removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.card_view));
```

Comment: Sorry! That didn't fix the issue for me.